# Visual Studio javascript intellisense customization

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I am trying to customize intellisense in a javascript function in visual studio without annotating the function.

I have tried to push my own items:
[image]

but unfortunately this has no effect when toto has not been initialized somewhere.
But if toto exists:

[image]

so... simple question, is there a way to make the toto completion behave as if it have been defined? Is there a flag I missed?

Here are the fields I have found on the event args "e",

- **on undefined toto:**

  - target: null (undefined)
  - targetName: toto (string)
  - items:  (Array)
  - scope: members (string)
  - _$items:  (Array)
- **on defined toto:**

  - target: 1 (number)
  - targetName: toto (string)
  - items: [object Object],... (Array)
  - scope: members (string)
  - _$items: [object Object],... (Array)

I have tried to change several field values, I does not seem to have any effect.
I am using VS2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found a way to add intellisense to function parameters without param annotations.
If the function has been called during intellisense runtime life cycle, it stores the type of the value passed into parameter.
Here I call my method with number 5, the completion behaves as if toto was of type Number.

[image]

Moreover, I found this:

from msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh395059.aspx

> A parameter is declared, but it has not been called elsewhere in the
>   active document, as shown in the following example.

```
function illuminate(light) {
         light.  // Accurate statement completion is not available 
                 // unless illuminate is called elsewhere with a 
                 // parameter that has a value. If it is called only
                 // in a function that is a sibling to 
                 // illuminate(light) in the call hierarchy, the 
                 // IntelliSense engine also cannot determine the 
                 // parameter type.
     }
```